# How does TCP back pressure work with AWS ALB?

Tags: tcp, aws-elb

Based on this [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-listener-config.html) both layer 4 and layer 7 ALBS terminate the client connection and establish a new TCP connection with the back-end instances (connection are reused on both ends).

- Is there any info on how these connections are managed? (i.e 1 server
  connection per client connection?)
- How is TCP backpressure handled? If the server stops reading TCP packets, will the client be made aware of it so it can backpressure?